# Jasper Report : set sheet name when export to xls file

Tags: jasper-reports

I want set sheet name for my xls file when i export from jasper report.
I have tried this net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.all = value.
but the value must be set from field that i retreive from database. is it possible?
or anyone have tried before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name">
    <![CDATA[$F{FieldName}]]>
</propertyExpression>
```

For more details you can checkout http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/excel-export-dynamically-set-sheet-names

Comment: Hi @laura, thanks. it fixed.
but now, i have problem i want to set report height dynamically.
do you have any idea?

Comment: You should create a different question for that. In few words, report height has to be static, since when you compile the report, it validates the elements against it (if an element does not fit the height, the report won't compile). If you change the height, the report must be recompiled. You can do this from your java code if you retrieve the value you need.